# Count a fixed number of rows in Excel formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to create a formula that I want to include only 12 rows down from a certain field.

The main issue that I'm having is that I have a formula in the first row and it calculates things on fields A2:A13. I constantly add new rows at A2, this is a requirement. I want to keep the old data for archiving, but want the formula to only consider A2:A13 no matter how many rows I insert on top.

For more clarification, here is the formula:
=IF(COUNT(I11:I$26)=0,"N/A",INDEX(I11:I$26,MIN(IF(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(I11,ROW(I11:I$26)-ROW(I11),0)),ROW(I11:I$26)-ROW(I11)+1))))

Basically, I'm looking to figure out how to do A2:(A2+12).

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Use the
[INDIRECT function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261)
to refer to these cells inside the formula.
This function returns a valid cell reference from a given text string.

You would refer to `A2:(A2+11)` by
`INDIRECT("$A$2")` and `INDIRECT("$A$13")`.

Comment: @Emir You may also try INDIRECT("A2:A13") to replace A2:A13.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get the range A2:A13 and still be immune to damage from inserting cells would be:

```
=OFFSET(A1,1,0):OFFSET(A1,12,0)
```

Bear in mind its direct result is a dynamic array that wants to spill from A1 to A12 so using it alone would give the `#SPILL!` error. But you want to operate on the data, and if you do, everything will be fine. An example would be wrapping it with `SUM()`. Basically, any work you do with its data that results in the error would result in the same error using a different method, so level playing ground.

Both `OFFSET()` and `INDIRECT()` can build a range fairly easily. One person might prefer `OFFSET()` as one is building each piece with a formula, perhaps, and each is independent (so calculating a row offset to use will not directly interfere with calculating a column offset to use) where with `INDIRECT()` one is building a single STRING for the whole expression and the elements can get confusing as they are used to build it. For many, string building is a fearsome thing while simply calculating a value seems easy. Vice versa too, as many have no problem keeping track of the strings they are building even when they get complex.

Your use is very straightforward and uncomplicated, with no obvious desire for making your range dynamic, so either one would be very easy for you to use.

Other obvious ways to do such a thing such as `INDEX()` and `XLOOKUP()` have a problem in that their ranges would adjust when you insert a new cell to push the data down. ¡No bueno! You'd use something to avoid using `INDIRECT()` and have to use it IN that something to keep it in place... talk about rabbit holes!